# Is it possible to connect to MySQL which is in the Cloud Run container remotely?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to connect to MySQL which is in the Cloud Run container remotely?

---

**Details**

```
Server 1 (slave server) - I have a Docker container (in Google Cloud Run) with MySQL-Server in it.
   |
   |
   |
Server 2 (main server) - I want to connect to MySQL via PHP.
```

Is it possible to do this?

P.s

---

I trying it to do, but I can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudRun currently only supports exposing HTTP based applications, it actually isn't super clear in the documentation, but this is maybe the biggest hint:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#env-vars